# unable to create a heat map with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
 dput(head(tt,500))
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 15744, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 
15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15745, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 15746, 
15746, 15746, 15746, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 15747, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15749, 15749, 15749, 
15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 
15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 
15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 
15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 15749, 
15749), class = "Date"), TIME1 = structure(c(0.0100694444444444, 
0.0204976851851852, 0.0309143518518519, 0.0413310185185185, 0.0517476851851852, 
0.0621643518518519, 0.0725810185185185, 0.0830092592592593, 0.0934259259259259, 
0.103842592592593, 0.114259259259259, 0.124675925925926, 0.135092592592593, 
0.145520833333333, 0.1559375, 0.166354166666667, 0.176770833333333, 
0.1871875, 0.197604166666667, 0.208032407407407, 0.218449074074074, 
0.228865740740741, 0.239282407407407, 0.249699074074074, 0.260115740740741, 
0.270532407407407, 0.280960648148148, 0.291377314814815, 0.301793981481481, 
0.312210648148148, 0.322627314814815, 0.333043981481481, 0.343460648148148, 
0.353877314814815, 0.364293981481481, 0.374722222222222, 0.385138888888889, 
0.395555555555556, 0.405972222222222, 0.416388888888889, 0.426805555555556, 
0.437222222222222, 0.447650462962963, 0.45806712962963, 0.468483796296296, 
0.478900462962963, 0.48931712962963, 0.499733796296296, 0.510162037037037, 
0.520578703703704, 0.53099537037037, 0.541412037037037, 0.551828703703704, 
0.56224537037037, 0.572673611111111, 0.583090277777778, 0.593506944444444, 
0.603923611111111, 0.614340277777778, 0.624756944444444, 0.635185185185185, 
0.645601851851852, 0.656018518518519, 0.666435185185185, 0.676851851851852, 
0.687268518518519, 0.697685185185185, 0.708113425925926, 0.718530092592593, 
0.728946759259259, 0.739363425925926, 0.749780092592593, 0.760196759259259, 
0.770613425925926, 0.781030092592593, 0.791458333333333, 0.801875, 
0.812291666666667, 0.822708333333333, 0.833125, 0.843541666666667, 
0.853958333333333, 0.864375, 0.874803240740741, 0.885219907407407, 
0.895636574074074, 0.906053240740741, 0.916469907407407, 0.926886574074074, 
0.937303240740741, 0.947731481481481, 0.958148148148148, 0.968564814814815, 
0.978981481481481, 0.989398148148148, 0.999814814814815, 0.0100694444444444, 
0.0204861111111111, 0.0309027777777778, 0.0413310185185185, 0.0517476851851852, 
0.0621643518518519, 0.0725810185185185, 0.0829976851851852, 0.0934143518518518, 
0.103831018518519, 0.114259259259259, 0.124675925925926, 0.135092592592593, 
0.145509259259259, 0.155925925925926, 0.166342592592593, 0.176759259259259, 
0.1871875, 0.197604166666667, 0.208020833333333, 0.2184375, 0.228854166666667, 
0.239270833333333, 0.2496875, 0.260115740740741, 0.270532407407407, 
0.280949074074074, 0.291365740740741, 0.301782407407407, 0.312199074074074, 
0.322615740740741, 0.333032407407407, 0.343460648148148, 0.353877314814815, 
0.364293981481481, 0.374710648148148, 0.385127314814815, 0.395543981481481, 
0.405960648148148, 0.416377314814815, 0.426793981481481, 0.437222222222222, 
0.447638888888889, 0.458055555555556, 0.468472222222222, 0.478888888888889, 
0.489305555555556, 0.499722222222222, 0.510138888888889, 0.520555555555556, 
0.530983796296296, 0.541400462962963, 0.55181712962963, 0.562233796296296, 
0.572650462962963, 0.58306712962963, 0.593483796296296, 0.603900462962963, 
0.61431712962963, 0.624733796296296, 0.635162037037037, 0.645578703703704, 
0.65599537037037, 0.666412037037037, 0.676828703703704, 0.68724537037037, 
0.697662037037037, 0.708078703703704, 0.71849537037037, 0.728912037037037, 
0.739340277777778, 0.749756944444444, 0.760173611111111, 0.770590277777778, 
0.781006944444444, 0.791423611111111, 0.801840277777778, 0.812256944444444, 
0.822673611111111, 0.833101851851852, 0.843518518518519, 0.853935185185185, 
0.864351851851852, 0.874768518518519, 0.885185185185185, 0.895601851851852, 
0.906018518518519, 0.916446759259259, 0.926863425925926, 0.937280092592593, 
0.947696759259259, 0.958113425925926, 0.968530092592593, 0.978946759259259, 
0.989363425925926, 0.999780092592593, 0.0100694444444444, 0.0204861111111111, 
0.0309143518518519, 0.0413310185185185, 0.0517476851851852, 0.0621643518518519, 
0.0725810185185185, 0.0829976851851852, 0.0934259259259259, 0.103842592592593, 
0.114259259259259, 0.124675925925926, 0.135092592592593, 0.145509259259259, 
0.1559375, 0.166354166666667, 0.176770833333333, 0.1871875, 0.197604166666667, 
0.208020833333333, 0.218449074074074, 0.228865740740741, 0.239282407407407, 
0.249699074074074, 0.260115740740741, 0.270532407407407, 0.280949074074074, 
0.291377314814815, 0.301793981481481, 0.312210648148148, 0.322627314814815, 
0.333043981481481, 0.343460648148148, 0.353888888888889, 0.364305555555556, 
0.374722222222222, 0.385138888888889, 0.395555555555556, 0.405972222222222, 
0.416400462962963, 0.42681712962963, 0.437233796296296, 0.447650462962963, 
0.45806712962963, 0.468483796296296, 0.478935185185185, 0.489363425925926, 
0.499780092592593, 0.510208333333333, 0.520625, 0.531041666666667, 
0.541458333333333, 0.551875, 0.562303240740741, 0.572719907407407, 
0.583136574074074, 0.593553240740741, 0.603969907407407, 0.614386574074074, 
0.624803240740741, 0.635219907407407, 0.645636574074074, 0.656064814814815, 
0.666481481481481, 0.676898148148148, 0.687314814814815, 0.697731481481481, 
0.708148148148148, 0.718564814814815, 0.728981481481481, 0.739409722222222, 
0.749826388888889, 0.760243055555556, 0.770659722222222, 0.781076388888889, 
0.791493055555556, 0.801909722222222, 0.812337962962963, 0.82275462962963, 
0.833171296296296, 0.843587962962963, 0.85400462962963, 0.864421296296296, 
0.874837962962963, 0.88525462962963, 0.895671296296296, 0.906099537037037, 
0.916516203703704, 0.926909722222222, 0.937337962962963, 0.947777777777778, 
0.958206018518518, 0.968530092592593, 0.978958333333333, 0.989375, 
0.999791666666667, 0.0100694444444444, 0.0204976851851852, 0.0309143518518519, 
0.0413310185185185, 0.0517476851851852, 0.0621759259259259, 0.0725925925925926, 
0.0830092592592593, 0.0934375, 0.103854166666667, 0.114270833333333, 
0.124699074074074, 0.135115740740741, 0.145532407407407, 0.155960648148148, 
0.166377314814815, 0.176805555555556, 0.187222222222222, 0.197650462962963, 
0.20806712962963, 0.21849537037037, 0.228912037037037, 0.239340277777778, 
0.249768518518519, 0.260185185185185, 0.270601851851852, 0.281030092592593, 
0.291446759259259, 0.301863425925926, 0.312280092592593, 0.322696759259259, 
0.333125, 0.343541666666667, 0.353958333333333, 0.364375, 0.374791666666667, 
0.385219907407407, 0.395636574074074, 0.406053240740741, 0.416469907407407, 
0.426886574074074, 0.437314814814815, 0.447731481481482, 0.458148148148148, 
0.468564814814815, 0.478981481481482, 0.489409722222222, 0.499826388888889, 
0.510243055555556, 0.520659722222222, 0.531076388888889, 0.54150462962963, 
0.551921296296296, 0.562337962962963, 0.57275462962963, 0.583171296296296, 
0.593599537037037, 0.604016203703704, 0.61443287037037, 0.624849537037037, 
0.635266203703704, 0.64568287037037, 0.656111111111111, 0.666527777777778, 
0.676944444444444, 0.687361111111111, 0.697777777777778, 0.708194444444444, 
0.718611111111111, 0.729039351851852, 0.739456018518518, 0.749872685185185, 
0.760289351851852, 0.770706018518518, 0.781134259259259, 0.791550925925926, 
0.801967592592593, 0.812384259259259, 0.822800925925926, 0.833229166666667, 
0.843645833333333, 0.8540625, 0.864479166666667, 0.874895833333333, 
0.885324074074074, 0.895740740740741, 0.906157407407407, 0.916574074074074, 
0.927002314814815, 0.937418981481482, 0.947835648148148, 0.958252314814815, 
0.968668981481482, 0.979097222222222, 0.989513888888889, 0.999930555555556, 
0.0100810185185185, 0.0204976851851852, 0.0309143518518519, 0.0413310185185185, 
0.0517476851851852, 0.0621759259259259, 0.0725925925925926, 0.0830092592592593, 
0.0934259259259259, 0.103854166666667, 0.114270833333333, 0.1246875, 
0.135104166666667, 0.145532407407407, 0.155949074074074, 0.166365740740741, 
0.176793981481481, 0.187210648148148, 0.197627314814815, 0.208055555555556, 
0.218472222222222, 0.228888888888889, 0.239305555555556, 0.249733796296296, 
0.260150462962963, 0.27056712962963, 0.280983796296296, 0.291412037037037, 
0.301828703703704, 0.31224537037037, 0.322662037037037, 0.333078703703704, 
0.343506944444444, 0.353923611111111, 0.364340277777778, 0.374756944444444, 
0.385173611111111, 0.395601851851852, 0.406018518518519, 0.416435185185185, 
0.426851851851852, 0.437268518518519, 0.447696759259259, 0.458113425925926, 
0.468530092592593, 0.478946759259259, 0.489363425925926, 0.499780092592593, 
0.510208333333333, 0.520625, 0.531041666666667, 0.541458333333333, 
0.551875, 0.562303240740741, 0.572719907407407, 0.583136574074074, 
0.593553240740741, 0.603969907407407, 0.614398148148148, 0.624814814814815, 
0.635231481481481, 0.645648148148148, 0.656064814814815, 0.666481481481481, 
0.676909722222222, 0.687326388888889, 0.697743055555556, 0.708159722222222, 
0.718576388888889, 0.728993055555556, 0.739421296296296, 0.749837962962963, 
0.76025462962963, 0.770671296296296, 0.781087962962963, 0.791516203703704, 
0.80193287037037, 0.812349537037037, 0.822766203703704, 0.83318287037037, 
0.843611111111111, 0.854027777777778, 0.864444444444444, 0.874861111111111, 
0.885277777777778, 0.895694444444444, 0.906122685185185, 0.916539351851852, 
0.926956018518518, 0.937372685185185, 0.947800925925926, 0.958217592592593, 
0.968634259259259, 0.979050925925926, 0.989467592592593, 0.999895833333333, 
0.0100810185185185, 0.0204976851851852, 0.0309143518518519, 0.0413310185185185, 
0.0517476851851852, 0.0621643518518519, 0.0725810185185185, 0.0830092592592593, 
0.0934259259259259, 0.103842592592593, 0.114270833333333, 0.1246875, 
0.135104166666667, 0.145520833333333, 0.155949074074074, 0.166365740740741, 
0.176782407407407, 0.187210648148148, 0.197627314814815, 0.208043981481481
), format = "h:m:s", class = "times"), CPU = c(27.7058823529412, 
28.1, 25.5444444444444, 24.4333333333333, 25.3222222222222, 22.3666666666667, 
20.8555555555556, 19.5777777777778, 20.8555555555556, 20.0333333333333, 
19.1888888888889, 18.5444444444444, 19.3333333333333, 19.0222222222222, 
17.3111111111111, 17.2777777777778, 17.2777777777778, 17.1555555555556, 
17.2333333333333, 17.3777777777778, 17.5444444444444, 18.2222222222222, 
17.7444444444444, 18.6333333333333, 21.6333333333333, 23.9, 27.9666666666667, 
28.5222222222222, 32.1777777777778, 33.0111111111111, 36.5222222222222, 
38.1111111111111, 43.8, 48.1666666666667, 52.4222222222222, 54.4444444444444, 
60.8222222222222, 64.7111111111111, 60.5777777777778, 65.9111111111111, 
67.3777777777778, 65.7777777777778, 66.6555555555556, 67.9888888888889, 
70.9777777777778, 70.6888888888889, 66.3777777777778, 68.3, 66.0222222222222, 
66.1777777777778, 64.9333333333333, 63.8, 66.1444444444444, 65.2888888888889, 
63.1222222222222, 61.1666666666667, 62.9, 62.6444444444444, 60.9888888888889, 
60.2222222222222, 57.8555555555556, 56.9333333333333, 56.1555555555556, 
57, 53.0222222222222, 54.2222222222222, 54.0333333333333, 52.5777777777778, 
52.0333333333333, 51.6111111111111, 49.0444444444444, 48.3777777777778, 
48.3444444444444, 50.1666666666667, 47.2, 44.4888888888889, 44.5111111111111, 
43.7222222222222, 40.6111111111111, 39.2888888888889, 39.5333333333333, 
36.6555555555556, 34.1888888888889, 33.6111111111111, 33.9222222222222, 
33.3, 31.0777777777778, 29.8333333333333, 29.3444444444444, 29.7888888888889, 
27.3888888888889, 25.9444444444444, 24.0666666666667, 23.4, 26.6666666666667, 
26.5888888888889, 30.5294117647059, 25.7333333333333, 27.2666666666667, 
26.7, 24.8666666666667, 23.3666666666667, 23.6333333333333, 21.7, 
19.6666666666667, 22.4666666666667, 19.2333333333333, 20.9, 18.4333333333333, 
19.6666666666667, 19.2666666666667, 19.8666666666667, 18.8666666666667, 
18.3666666666667, 16.1666666666667, 15.6333333333333, 15.9333333333333, 
17.1333333333333, 18.3, 23.7333333333333, 22.4, 20.4333333333333, 
18.9666666666667, 19.3333333333333, 22.8333333333333, 25.0333333333333, 
26.5333333333333, 29.7333333333333, 34.1666666666667, 35.9333333333333, 
39.1, 37.4, 43.9, 38.6333333333333, 46.0333333333333, 49.2, 49.0666666666667, 
54.1666666666667, 54.6333333333333, 52, 57.6666666666667, 54.5333333333333, 
53.2, 53.8, 54.0666666666667, 61.0666666666667, 56.7333333333333, 
53.6, 52.7, 54.9, 51.0333333333333, 53.9333333333333, 52, 49.3, 
48.3666666666667, 48.1333333333333, 46.0333333333333, 46.8333333333333, 
42.9333333333333, 47.0666666666667, 49.1, 48.6666666666667, 48.4, 
42.7333333333333, 45.2333333333333, 37, 37.7666666666667, 36.1333333333333, 
40.3666666666667, 39.8666666666667, 36.6333333333333, 38.7666666666667, 
40, 34.4666666666667, 34.0333333333333, 35.5, 35.8666666666667, 
30.3666666666667, 38.5666666666667, 27.4, 29.3666666666667, 39.6, 
45.4333333333333, 61.4666666666667, 62.6666666666667, 61.7, 63.7666666666667, 
61.6, 49.8, 52.2666666666667, 44.2666666666667, 37.9, 27.6428571428571, 
26.6, 24.4333333333333, 25.1444444444444, 26.5555555555556, 22.0666666666667, 
19.8, 19.9555555555556, 20.1111111111111, 18.2444444444444, 18.4333333333333, 
17.1777777777778, 17.4333333333333, 18.5777777777778, 17.6888888888889, 
16.1111111111111, 17.6777777777778, 17.4333333333333, 16.0888888888889, 
17.0444444444444, 16.0444444444444, 15.1777777777778, 14.1888888888889, 
16.0888888888889, 17.4222222222222, 17.0222222222222, 18.2111111111111, 
20.6, 21.2111111111111, 21.9, 23.1888888888889, 24.9888888888889, 
27.7, 30.9333333333333, 32.9444444444444, 35.4333333333333, 36.6666666666667, 
40.2333333333333, 39.2222222222222, 40.3777777777778, 45.2444444444444, 
46.7666666666667, 48.3777777777778, 51.5888888888889, 53.5222222222222, 
42.3157894736842, 34.7866666666667, 32.7733333333333, 36.4466666666667, 
31.98, 36.8133333333333, 34.34, 34.8, 34.0266666666667, 33.7733333333333, 
32.1266666666667, 33.3066666666667, 34.4733333333333, 31.82, 
31.8, 33.84, 33.78, 31.9066666666667, 29.7666666666667, 28.3466666666667, 
28.62, 27.9866666666667, 28.82, 27.5, 29.4466666666667, 27.92, 
28.0733333333333, 27.2666666666667, 28.0533333333333, 27.52, 
25.8866666666667, 26.38, 26.8933333333333, 26.36, 25.88, 25.96, 
26.8133333333333, 23.9133333333333, 26.4066666666667, 25.08, 
23.7933333333333, 21.2333333333333, 17.3666666666667, 16.4807692307692, 
16.9777777777778, 14.9555555555556, 16.3218390804598, 28.8684210526316, 
31.6, 38.1, 35.3, 21.8627450980392, 19.3, 17, 16.7, 16.1444444444444, 
14.3, 13.7333333333333, 13.4777777777778, 13.0333333333333, 12.1666666666667, 
11.3, 11.9111111111111, 11.3222222222222, 11.4555555555556, 10.5333333333333, 
10.7777777777778, 10.9111111111111, 11.1, 9.28888888888889, 9.35555555555556, 
9.95555555555556, 10, 9.47777777777778, 10.3333333333333, 11.3222222222222, 
12.3333333333333, 14.1555555555556, 15.3555555555556, 17.1777777777778, 
19.0888888888889, 20.1555555555556, 21.5444444444444, 26.0555555555556, 
29.2777777777778, 31.1666666666667, 32.5333333333333, 36.5555555555556, 
39.3555555555556, 41.6888888888889, 45.4888888888889, 46.7333333333333, 
49.5111111111111, 50.6777777777778, 49.8555555555556, 50.2777777777778, 
51.4666666666667, 47.0333333333333, 48.6, 51.1888888888889, 48.6555555555556, 
46.5, 44.8444444444444, 45.9, 48.2333333333333, 46.7555555555556, 
45.3111111111111, 46.0888888888889, 48.5555555555556, 46.0555555555556, 
44.8777777777778, 44.5, 46.0666666666667, 45.6777777777778, 43.6, 
44.5888888888889, 46.0555555555556, 45.4111111111111, 44.7555555555556, 
43.3222222222222, 43.9888888888889, 43.1666666666667, 42.4777777777778, 
41.4, 40.7555555555556, 40.2111111111111, 39.7333333333333, 38.9555555555556, 
38.7111111111111, 38.9444444444444, 37.8222222222222, 37.5444444444444, 
38.1888888888889, 37.2444444444444, 36.7222222222222, 36.7333333333333, 
37.2333333333333, 35.3666666666667, 35.0444444444444, 34.7111111111111, 
33.5666666666667, 32.4111111111111, 30.6222222222222, 29.9444444444444, 
29.7888888888889, 29.7111111111111, 28.5, 27.6470588235294, 25.9, 
24.0222222222222, 22.0444444444444, 22.5888888888889, 19.9888888888889, 
17.3555555555556, 17.7555555555556, 17.6, 16.8, 16.2333333333333, 
16.1666666666667, 18.5555555555556, 19.0444444444444, 17.6111111111111, 
18, 18.3111111111111, 18.5333333333333, 18.2333333333333, 18.1888888888889, 
18.2555555555556, 19.1, 18.8777777777778, 19.1333333333333, 20.2777777777778, 
21.4111111111111, 23.4444444444444, 25.2777777777778, 27.3555555555556, 
29.2666666666667, 31.5555555555556, 32.0888888888889, 34.4333333333333, 
36.7444444444444, 38.5777777777778, 41.2555555555556, 42.9777777777778, 
44.7777777777778, 44.7444444444444, 44.9333333333333, 48.4666666666667, 
46.9888888888889, 47.3333333333333, 48.2777777777778, 47.1333333333333, 
48.3444444444444, 48.5555555555556, 51.4222222222222, 49.3444444444444, 
47.8222222222222, 45.5888888888889, 46.2888888888889, 47.5666666666667, 
45.0111111111111, 45.9111111111111, 46.6333333333333, 43.9777777777778, 
46.1777777777778, 44.9, 44.7777777777778, 45.7777777777778, 45.8444444444444, 
44.4666666666667, 44.1444444444444, 44.5111111111111, 44.5666666666667, 
42.7777777777778, 43.2666666666667, 43.0666666666667, 43.1222222222222, 
42.5, 40.6222222222222, 40.2555555555556, 40.7222222222222, 39.8888888888889, 
39.6333333333333, 39.1888888888889, 39.6777777777778, 39.1666666666667, 
39.5111111111111, 38.2666666666667, 39.0222222222222, 37.5666666666667, 
36.6888888888889, 37.4222222222222, 37.5777777777778, 36.8444444444444, 
35.7222222222222, 35.7444444444444, 35.9111111111111, 33.2111111111111, 
31.8555555555556, 29.5, 28.5888888888889, 27.6333333333333, 29.5555555555556, 
29.1960784313725, 28.5555555555556, 26.8333333333333, 25.3222222222222, 
25.1555555555556, 23.0555555555556, 22.1777777777778, 20.7333333333333, 
20.8222222222222, 20.8, 19.9444444444444, 19.5666666666667, 19, 
19.1888888888889, 18.5111111111111, 17.8777777777778, 17.6111111111111, 
18.3555555555556, 18.5777777777778, 19.0777777777778)), .Names = c("DATE", 
"TIME1", "CPU"), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

this part is Brian Diggs code to scale the y-axis:

```
library(scales)
timesreverse_trans <- function() {
    trans <- function(x) {-as.numeric(x)}
    inv <- function(x) {times(-x)}
    fmt <- function(x) {
        notone <- x != 1
        simplify <- !any(diff(x) < 1/(24*60))
        ifelse(notone,
               format(x-floor(x), simplify=simplify),
               ifelse(simplify, "24:00", "24:00:00"))
    }
    trans_new("chrontimes-reverse",
              transform = trans,
              inverse = inv,
              breaks = pretty_breaks(),
              format = fmt,
              domain=c(0,1))
}
scale_y_times <- function(..., trans=NULL) {
    scale_y_continuous(trans=timesreverse_trans(), ...)
}
```

I have this data frame tt. When I try to run this code, I dont see the color on the chart. Only very little dots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(chron)

val=c(0,0.29,0.39,0.49,0.59, 0.69,0.79, 0.89, 1)
cols=c("white","#F0FFFF","#AEEEEE","#ADD8E6","#33FFFF","green","yellow","orange", "#FF0000", "#FF0000")
brk = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
    ggplot(tt, aes(DATE, TIME1, fill=CPU)) + geom_tile() + theme_bw() + scale_fill_gradientn(name="CPU Utilization", colours=cols, values=val, limits=c(0,100), breaks = brk) + guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 5, keyheight = 1)) + scale_y_times()
```

When I subset the tt data frame to one it works.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(chron)

 val=c(0,0.29,0.39,0.49,0.59, 0.69,0.79, 0.89, 1)
cols=c("white","#F0FFFF","#AEEEEE","#ADD8E6","#33FFFF","green","yellow","orange", "#FF0000", "#FF0000")
brk = c(20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)

ggplot(subset(tt, DATE %in% as.Date(c("2013-02-08"))),aes(DATE, TIME1, fill=CPU)) + geom_tile() + theme_bw() + scale_fill_gradientn(name="CPU Utilization", colours=cols, values=val, limits=c(0,100), breaks = brk) + guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 5, keyheight = 1)) + scale_y_times()
```

Can somebody tell me how to address this problem?

Comment: Your example code doesn't run for me at all. We're missing `brk` and ggplot doesn't seem to know what to do with `TIME1`.

Comment: `cols` is missing as well

Comment: @joran, sorry for the mising parts. I've update my original post. Again, when I subset the data to one day, the heatmap looks good, but it does not work on the larger data set. I only see little spots on the chart.

Comment: Please try to make a reproducible example! To which package does `times` belong to?

Comment: @Beasterfield, it belongs to chron library, I've update the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `chron` package, so maybe this is not the best answer. Your problem originates from the values stored in `tt$Time1`. They are simply all to unequal to each other which means that for every single value a new tile is created in your plot. In the result your tiles become simply too thin. As far as I see, the best way to overcome this is by *rounding* the time points using `trunc`:

```
tt$TIME1 <- trunc(tt$TIME1, "0:15:00")
```

Calling then your original code gives

[image]

By the way, for so large data, I'd also suggest to use `geom_raster()` instead of `geom_tile()` since it's faster.